I am trying to figure out how to access the FishBowl Inventory API in a hosetd environment
I am working on a project to access the FishBowl Inventory when the server is in a FishBowl hosted environment. I have read through the docs and something seems to be missing. I have tried to configure Postman, but the endpoint does not seem to be correct as I do not get a response. Does the firewall of the server need to be opened for a specific port?
